# How to scrape content betweeen all link tags like <a href="">SCRAPE THIS</a> on a page?

Tags: php, xpath, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a site's link texts, i.e SCRAPE THIS. I want to do this for all links on the page. So far I have this:

```
<?php

$target_url = "SITE I WANT TO SCRAPE";

// make the cURL request to $target_url
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$html= curl_exec($ch);
if (!$html) {
    echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
    echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
    exit;
}

// parse the html into a DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all the on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a/text()");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    echo "<br />Link stored: $href";
}
?>
```

I'm pretty new to this stuff and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: what output does this give you and where is it wrong?

Comment: how about not fraudulently identifying yourself as the google bot.

Comment: Sorry for that, just found that script on a forum and tried it. Just get a blank screen. As I said, I'm new to this whole thing. My bad.

Comment: @Dagon - I wish I could +1 that more than once.

Comment: removed it, sorry! and +1 it again for you @adrewsi

Comment: I googled it and found the code here: http://merchantos.com/makebeta/php/scraping-links-with-php  no need to down grade a newb. I just wanted to learn some more and will be more carefull in the future when reading other peoples tutorials etc.

Comment: try to use RegEx, or see the related  at the right of this page :)

Comment: @MrBassam: I hope you're kidding about using regex :-P

Comment: @Rocket I like RegEx and use it everywhere it makes life easer at least for me :)

Comment: @MrBassam: RegEx is the wrong tool for parsing HTML.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454\

Comment: @Rocket Thank you, I will change my mind, Thnak you agin :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for loop, `$href` is not a string.  It's actually a DOMText node.  In order to use it as a string, you need to access its `nodeValue` property.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    echo "<br />Link stored: $href->nodeValue";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a/text()");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i)->textContent;
    echo "<br />Link stored: $href";
}
```